# ILmerge does not implement Newtonsoft.json

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ilmerge

The second day I beat my head against the wall and can not figure it out.
How it is possible to implement this dll, any mistakes constantly jump out.
I tried many different options that are on the Internet. Nothing helped.
Help me figure out how to solve the problem.
How to implement Newtonsoft.Json in my project via ILMerge?
Thank you in advance.

Error:

> leave command
>   ""C:\Users\User\Desktop\FastFoodDemo\ILMerge\merge_all.bat"
>   "C:\Users\User\Desktop\FastFoodDemo\"
>   "C:\Users\User\Desktop\FastFoodDemo\FastFoodDemo\bin\Debug\RCC.exe"
>   Debug" with code 1.   FastFoodDemo

Event final assembly:

> "$(SolutionDir)\ILMerge\merge_all.bat" "$(SolutionDir)" "$(TargetPath)" $(ConfigurationName)

merge_all.bat

```html
@ECHO OFF

rem #    set .NET version and output folder name
set net="v4, C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319"
set output=Output

rem #    process arguments
set ILMergeSolution=%1ILMerge\ILMerge.exe

rem # determine programm files of x86 for 32 and 64 Platform
IF     EXIST "%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%" set prorgammFiles=%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%
IF NOT EXIST "%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%" set prorgammFiles=%PROGRAMFILES%

rem # if ILMerge.exe not in the $(SolutionDir)ILMerge\
rem #  then try to use installed in prorgammFiles
IF     EXIST %ILMergeSolution% set ILMerge="%ILMergeSolution%"
IF NOT EXIST %ILMergeSolution% set ILMerge=%prorgammFiles%\Microsoft\ILMerge\ILMerge.exe

set target_path=%2
set target_file=%~nx2
set target_dir=%~dp2
set ConfigurationName=%3

rem #    set output path and result file path
set outdir=%target_dir%%output%
set result=%outdir%\%target_file%

rem #    print info
@echo     Start %ConfigurationName% Merging %target_file%. 
@echo Target: %target_path%
@echo target_dir: %target_dir%
@echo Config: %ConfigurationName% 

rem #    recreate outdir
IF EXIST "%outdir%" rmdir /S /Q "%outdir%"
md "%outdir%"

rem #    run merge cmd
@echo Merging: '"%ILMerge%" /wildcards /targetplatform:%net% /out:"%result%" %target_path% "%target_dir%*.dll"'
"%ILMerge%" /wildcards /targetplatform:%net% /out:"%result%" %target_path% "%target_dir%*.dll"

rem #    if succeded
IF %ErrorLevel% EQU 0 (
    
    rem #    clear real output folder and put there result assembly
    IF %ConfigurationName%==Release (

        del  %target_dir%*.*
        del  %target_dir%*.dll
        del  %target_dir%*.pdb
        del  %target_dir%*.xml
        del  %target_dir%*.*
        
        copy %result% %target_dir%
        rmdir /S /Q %outdir%
        set result=%target_path% 
        @echo Result: %target_file% "->  %target_path%"
    ) ELSE (
       @echo Result: %target_file% "->  %result%" )
   
   set status=succeded
   set errlvl=0    
) ELSE (
    set status=failed 
    set errlvl=1
    )

@echo Merge %status%
exit %errlvl%
```

Comment: Could you provide a way of us reproducing the problem, please? It's very hard to help with a fairly vague description.

Comment: Could you restate this in the form "I did this, I expect this, I got this"? Posting a reference to some batch file we don't have that exited with a code 1 that may or may not mean something isn't helpful. What's the actual output of ILMerge and how are you invoking it?

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json has a pdb file, it is written that most likely it interferes with the implementation of the library via ILMerge.

The problem is that I have a bunch of dlls that are being implemented without problems via ILMerge, but it's Newtonsoft.Json that does not want to intrude and produces such an error. He just does not want to compile the project in exe and that's it.
(Edit my post).